# Retrofit Giving Wrong data

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Okay, So i am currently working on weather forecast Android App and for that i am using openweathermap API for fetching weather Data. I am getting this response for 5 days weatherforecast. See my Json Response that API gives me [here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb994c2a). Now when i parse same API using Retrofit some of the values which i get are either 0 or null. See the Response i get using Retrofit [here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbd36600). You can easily see the difference in Temp_max, Temp_min and other values as the values in API response is correct, but retrofit gives those values as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using exact naming conventions as you got JsonObject or JsonArray from your API Response or use @SerializeName() from Gson, if you want to use different variable names, Hope this Helps.